# Exclude values already in file - Foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-4.0

Please help me to correct the below code . I am trying to exclude the filename which already received email but `-and $i.file -ne $SentUsers` is not excluding the already sent filenames.

I am trying below things:

1. Write filename to a file
2. Get filename to a file
3. Exclude filename which already recieved an email by using `-and $i.file -ne $SentUsers`
4. Copy new current file name to file by overwriting existing file

Below is my full code:

```
$Q  = "
*** SQLCode Here ***
"
$ab = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Serv1 -Database DB1 -Query $Q

## Write filename to a file
$l = $ab | select file | Out-File C:\temp\fname.txt

## Get filename to a file
$SentUsers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\fname.txt

foreach ($i in $cr) {
    ## Exclude filename which already recieved an email by using -and $i.file -ne $SentUsers

    if ($i.Uid -eq 'No' -and $i.UIntheTeam -eq 'No' -and $i.file -ne $SentUsers ) {
        $user = $i.User
        Send-MailMessage -To @("abc") -Cc $user -From 'abc1' -SMTPServer abc.co.jp -Subject "TestSub" -Body "
** Mail Message Body Here **
"
    } else {
        'Exit'
    }
}

# Copy new current file name to file by overwriting existing file
$ab | select file | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\fname.txt
```

Comment: It looks like $SentUsers is an array.  You want to use -notin instead of -ne.

Comment: @mjolinor , I used -notin clause but still i am getting the email for which user already received email.Can you please suggest what else can i do to stop $user receive email only once if he meets condition. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison between if the file exists within the $SentUsers is reversed. You need to be asking is my file inside this collection?

Turn it around and put in $SentUsers -notcontains $i.file.

This should return true/false depending on the content of $SentUsers.

Also you may need to separate your comparisons with (). Overall I'd change your if statement like so:

```
(($i.Uid -eq 'No') -and ($i.UIntheTeam -eq 'No') -and ($SentUsers -notcontains $i.file))
```